# find path between two city in array php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have one list array like as:

```
$boardingCollection = array(
array(
    "Departure" => "Stockholm",
    "Arrival" => "New York",
    "Transportation" => "Plane",
    "TransportationNumber" => "SK22",
    "Seat" => "7B",
    "Gate" => "22"
),
array(
    "Departure" => "Madrid",
    "Arrival" => "Barcelona",
    "Transportation" => "Train",
    "TransportationNumber" => "78A",
    "Seat" => "45B"
),
array(
    "Departure" => "Gerona Airport",
    "Arrival" => "Stockholm",
    "Transportation" => "Plane",
    "TransportationNumber" => "SK455",
    "Seat" => "3A",
    "Gate" => "45B",
    "Baggage" => "334"
),
array(
    "Departure" => "Barcelona",
    "Arrival" => "Gerona Airport",
    "Transportation" => "Bus"
),);
```

now , i want that find path between Departure to Arrival so then will be sort list
output like as this:

•  Take    train   78A from    Madrid  to  Barcelona.  Seat    number: 45B
•  Take the airport bus from    Barcelona   to  Gerona  Airport.    No  seat    assignment.
•  From Gerona  Airport,    take    flight  SK455   to  Stockholm.  Gate    45B,    seat    3A.
Baggage drop    at  ticket  counter 344.
•  From Stockholm,  take    flight  SK22    to  New York    JFK.    Gate    22B,    seat    7B.
Baggage will    we  automatically   transferred from    your    last    leg.

Comment: You'll need to write code for that.

Comment: what have you tried? show us your best attempt(code) so we can help you solve any issue(s) you encounter.

Comment: @ScottHunter my problem is write this code :))

Comment: Make a hashset of departure and arrival and use a while loop to from source to dest.

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks but how do i find path and sort this paths like output?

Comment: @mahdinorouzi Are you given a source already to start with in the form of a string? Also is the array with the baggage always the last stop?

Comment: @vivek_23 no only told that you have a list like as  arrays above and from this list must be find and  will  be sort

Comment: @mahdinorouzi If you are not given the source stop to start with, then what's the point of this itinerary?

Comment: @vivek_23 this arrays are kart of travel that must be sort of source to des

Comment: @mahdinorouzi Ok, I figured it out.

Comment: @vivek_23 please help me for solve this

Comment: How can anyone *help* you when you have presented no code one could help you with?

Comment: First, you'll need something to specify the format of the output. Research string formatting in PHP. Second, you'll need something to loop over pairs of arrays, matching Departure and Arrival entries. Research loops, nested loops, and conditional statements. Third, you'll need to decide what you want to do when information is missing or only present for some records. Depending on where in that process you're stuck, you could get at least six different questions out of this. Do the usual programming approach: Break the big problem into smaller chunks. Tackle each of the small chunks. Recurse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get source and destination, you will need to do an [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) of all `Departure` and `Arrival` keys.

Now, you just need to iterate from source to destination data and print the text according to the `Transportation`. To get the value of any `departure` data in O(1) time on average, you can re-index your data using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php 


$boardingCollection = array(
    array(
        "Departure" => "Stockholm",
        "Arrival" => "New York",
        "Transportation" => "Plane",
        "TransportationNumber" => "SK22",
        "Seat" => "7B",
        "Gate" => "22"
    ),
    array(
        "Departure" => "Madrid",
        "Arrival" => "Barcelona",
        "Transportation" => "Train",
        "TransportationNumber" => "78A",
        "Seat" => "45B"
    ),
    array(
        "Departure" => "Gerona Airport",
        "Arrival" => "Stockholm",
        "Transportation" => "Plane",
        "TransportationNumber" => "SK455",
        "Seat" => "3A",
        "Gate" => "45B",
        "Baggage" => "334"
    ),
    array(
        "Departure" => "Barcelona",
        "Arrival" => "Gerona Airport",
        "Transportation" => "Bus"
    )
);


function getSourceAndDest($boardingCollection){
    $dept_set = array_column($boardingCollection,null,'Departure');
    $arrival_set = array_column($boardingCollection,null,'Arrival');
    $source_diff = array_diff(array_keys($dept_set),array_keys($arrival_set));
    $dest_diff = array_diff(array_keys($arrival_set),array_keys($dept_set));
    $source = array_shift($source_diff);
    $destination = array_shift($dest_diff);
    return array(
        $source,
        $destination
    );
}

function printItinerary($source_and_dest,$boardingCollection){
    $source = $source_and_dest[0];
    $dest = $source_and_dest[1];
    $stops_index = array_column($boardingCollection,null,'Departure');
    
    while($source != $dest){
        $stop = $stops_index[$source];
        if($stop['Transportation'] == 'Bus'){
            echo "Take the airport bus from $source to ".$stop['Arrival'].". No seat assignment.",PHP_EOL;
        }else if($stop['Transportation'] == 'Plane'){
            echo "From $source, take flight ".$stop['TransportationNumber']." to ". $stop['Arrival'].". ";
            echo "Gate ". $stop['Gate']. ", seat ".$stop['Seat'],". ";
            if(isset($stop['Baggage'])){
                echo "Baggage drop at ticket counter ".$stop['Baggage'].".",PHP_EOL;
            }else{
                echo "Baggage will we automatically transferred from your last leg.",PHP_EOL;
            }
        }else if($stop['Transportation'] == 'Train'){
            echo "Take train ".$stop['TransportationNumber']." from $source to ".$stop['Arrival'],". ";
            echo "Seat number: ".$stop['Seat'].".",PHP_EOL;
        }else{
            // you figure out what to print
        }
        
        $source = $stop['Arrival'];
    }
}


printItinerary(getSourceAndDest($boardingCollection),$boardingCollection);
```

Comment: @mahdinorouzi The while loop goes from source to destination and prints the text according to `Bus`,`Train` or `Plane`. The `getSourceAndDest()` just finds the source and destination stations out of your data as source cannot be present as `arrival` anywhere and destination cannot be present as `departure` anywhere.